# Contact form redirecting after submit but result page displays wrong styles

Tags: php, jquery, forms, html

Form sending, validation and redirecting works but thank you page displays wrong styles. I am not experienced coder and don't know how to fix the code to display correct styles.

Here's [Form](http://www.villalotus.net/TEST/TESTVILLALOTUS/jquerytemp.html) and [Thank you page](http://www.villalotus.net/TEST/TESTVILLALOTUS/kiitosviesti.html)

```
<?php
$email_to = my@email;
$email_subject = "Contact";
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$thankyouurl = "http://www.villalotus.net/TEST/TESTVILLALOTUS/kiitosviesti.html";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header( "Location: $thankyouurl");
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go directly to this link: http://www.villalotus.net/TEST/TESTVILLALOTUS/kiitosviesti.html (your thank you page) this page display's correctly? This error occour only when the page is loaded before sending the  email?

I'm not sure about that but, try switch this : `header( "Location: $thankyouurl");` for this:
`header("location:kiitosviesti.html");`

Note: In your second line of the script add quotes to email

Comment: Yes, thank you page 'kiitosviesti.html' displays styles correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing to do with the form submission PHP you've posted - the styling is different because the two pages are using different stylesheets and have totally different markup.

The form submission page is using the css file `jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css`

The thank you page is using this css file `thankyou.css`

Both are in your CSS directory.  You will need to do some reading on CSS if you want to work out how to style the two pages so they look the same, that's well beyond the scope of an SO answer.  Comparing those two stylesheets will at least show you the differences and help you work towards getting the pages looking the same.

Comment: Thanks McNab!I will combine styles on one stylesheets.